# How can I extract a value from a string like the following?

Tags: python

I want to extract the value from a "string" using the name of a key.

My code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request


response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NSE:RELCAPITAL&output=json')
html =str(response.read(),'utf-8')
    print(html)
```

The output I receive is:

```
"symbol" : "RELCAPITAL",
"exchange" : "NSE",
"id": "374785",
"t" : "RELCAPITAL",
"e" : "NSE",
"name" : "Reliance Capital Limited"
, "f_reuters_url" : "http:\x2F\x2Fstocks.us.reuters.com\x2Fstocks\x2Fratios.asp?rpc=66\x26symbol=RLCP.NS",
"f_recent_quarter_date" : "", 
"f_annual_date" : "",
```

I want to select the value of the `symbol` key. How should I achieve that?

Comment: why do you make it a string in the first place? it looks like you're getting a json response back. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you make some effort on your part to start with? Not to be disrespectful, but I didn't even see the code which displays your output.

Comment: i use json but it give me error so i make it string i want the last trading price of relcapital i am getting price by slicing string but site change regular and slicing location changes so there is any other thing for getting price by asking key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex`:

```
import re

symbol = re.search("symbol\"[\s:\"]*(.*?)\"")

if (symbol):
    print(symbol.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not provide more details about your problem, there are only open-ended answers.

I will try to answer by saying that:

1. If the data type you are dealing with is really `str`, then you should try using the `re` module from the standard library. That lets you use regular expressions and, in a certain way, add structure to unstructured data;
2. If instead the data you get is represented by a `dict` instance or some other structured data type object, fetching the key's value should be as immediate as doing `do_something(response["symbol"])`.

Unfortunately answers to these kind of questions are all dependent on what programming interfaces you are using, and providing an a-priori solution can only be done in general terms.